# Program type already present: com.squareup.picasso.Action$RequestWeakReference

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, build.gradle

When I try to compile the code, the following error appears on Android Studio 3.2.1

```
Program type already present: com.squareup.picasso.Action$RequestWeakReference
```

My gradle code:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.0.4'
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportlib_version"
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportlib_version"
implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportlib_version"
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportlib_version"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:$exoplayer_version"
implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-rtmp:$exoplayer_version"
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.7.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.10.3'
implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.6'
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.6@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.4.4@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

How do I fix my gradle script to fix the error?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this applies to you since I don't see it as a gradle dependency for you, but I got a similar error when I had the Picasso .jar file in my /libs directory AND had it listed as a dependency in my gradle script. I removed it from my lib directory and just left the dependency in gradle and it worked. Do you have the .jar file somewhere twice?